# C++ Setup for beginners in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation

Im just asking a generic question from a begginer programmer: How do I setup/configure visual studio express 2013 for a begginer?

Im asking as Im having trouble compiling a simple 'Hello World' Program.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

These are the errors:

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier c:\users\blake\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\hello world\hello world\app.xaml.cpp   6   1   Hello world
Error   2   error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier c:\users\blake\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\hello world\hello world\app.xaml.cpp   6   1   Hello world
Warning 3   warning C4447: 'main' signature found without threading model. Consider using 'int main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ args)'. c:\users\blake\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\hello world\hello world\app.xaml.cpp   8   1   Hello world
    4   IntelliSense: identifier "cout" is undefined    c:\Users\Blake\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hello world\Hello world\App.xaml.cpp   6   2   Hello world
    5   IntelliSense: identifier "endl" is undefined    c:\Users\Blake\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hello world\Hello world\App.xaml.cpp   6   28  Hello world
```

I have turned off precompiled headers, but I'm still getting the issues.

I know if i put STD:: in-front of the cout and endl I get rid of two of the errors. Mainly because I haven't used the namespace std. - I can fix this myself.

Anything else I need to do? - I need to set it up purely for a beginner, so I can compile and run straight away kinda thing!

Where do I run the compiled file?

Comment: You're using c++/cli? or some kind of managed c++? The signature of the main function in warning 3 as well as the references to app.xaml in warning 3-5 don't look like normal c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. File -> New -> Project.
2. In the Visual C++ project types pane, Click Win32 and then click on Win32 Console Application.
3. Type a name for the project, click OK.
4. In the Win32 Application Wizard, click Next, select 'Empty Project' and then click Finish.

   - this step is important.

Source and link to the full guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235629.aspx
Guide for Visual Studio Express with images: http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/visualstudio

Now the following code should work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As it stands, the console window will exit immediately after the program finishes executing.   You may want to set a breakpoint before the return statement to see the output of the program.

Comment: See above image - Where is win32?

Comment: Sorry I don't see the image - is it in your original post?  Check out this tutorial with images - it might help: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/visualstudio/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a line after the "include" line and write

```
using namespace std;
```